# Powershell invoke-WebRequest PUT call

Tags: powershell

Hello I am trying to access a local API of a device in my home and I have run in to a problem that I can't figure out.

So what I need to do is to place a put call and send a parameter to the device in the example they use:

```
curl -i -d app="Example app" -X PUT http://0.0.0.0/api/token
```

So I have tried some different options but I can't get it right this is what I have done and believe is "most correct" among other things i have tried:

```
#$headers = @{app="testapp"}
#$test = Invoke-WebRequest "http://192.168.0.10/api/token" -Method Put -Headers $headers -UseBasicParsing
```

I can't figure out that would be the -d  equivalent is powersell, anyone done this before? that can point me in the right direction.

Thanks.

Comment: What data structure does the API expect? JSON? Do you need to authenticate? What are your error messages? -d contains the data you're sending and depending on the API endpoint, it could either be part of the URL, part of the Headers or part of the Body.

Comment: Just for simplicity sake, you could download curl and just use it instead.